# Good approach to adding a blog to my website

Tags: php, codeigniter, blogs

I've built a custom website on top of the codeigniter framework. I now want to implement a 'blog' section of my website and allow various non-technical people I work with to edit/create blog entries and post them. I don't want to create a backend for this from scratch.

Are there any good plugins for codeigniter that work with existing blog hosting services to perhaps download an xml-rss feed and construct this into a blog page? Not sure what the best approach is to offer this kind of functionality to nontechnical people I work with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, not sure if it'll play along with the existing website, but Pyro CMS is built with Codeigniter and probably fits your need: http://pyrocms.com/
It's worth a try. :)

Comment: you could also try fuelCMS.. http://www.getfuelcms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simply the admin interface you don't want to write again, I would:

- Setup the blog on the same mysql server as your CodeIgniter app *OR* on a server with a static IP
- Create another db connection from your app to the blog's database
- Use CodeIgniter to handle data, routing and the frontend views

This will allow you to better integrate the frontend interface of the blog into your existing site while keeping the blog's backend.

If you don't (for some reason) want to create another connection, you could use the RSS feeds as an XML formatted API, or create an API layer on top of the blog. This option will definitely be slower than a direct connection, but you may prefer to do it this way.

Comment: you mention setting up the blog on a server, do you recommend any specific blogging software?

Comment: For easy article publishing etc, WordPress (http://wordpress.org) is a good choice. I've also heard good things about TextPattern (http://textpattern.com/), but I haven't used it personally

Comment: I'm curious what you think about this idea: What if I set up a blog with any of the major blogging providers, then had javascript download and parse the xml feed provided by blogging service and display that to the user, all client side. The goal of which would be to avoid load on my server to serve a blog

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, for a number of reasons. 1)Search engines wouldn't be able to read any of your blog's content. 2)Structuring URLs would be difficult, even with HTML5 History API. 3)Parsing XML in javascript could be slow. Instead of calling and parsing the XML on every request, you could cache the result and serve that data in the view.

Comment: Ah yeah I totally didn't think about SEO factors, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Almost all blogs provide RSS.  You could just consume that and cache it using an RSS Parser library.

I have a demo running right now using this method with Tumblr